# Amazon WAF setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I have requirement to allow a URL pattern only for a set of ip's.
For example the pattern is /helloworld.

for /helloworld pattern only certain ip's will be allowed other ip's must be blocked. Is it possible with amazon AWS. I tried creating a condition which matches string but I could not find a ip based rule for this condition.

Could you please let us know whether it is possible in aws waf?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

1) Create a rule that "Whitelists" a list of IPs.
2) Follow that rule with another rules that "Blacklists" everyone for your protected URL.

Create an IP Address Condition Set containing the allowed IP addresses, then a rule that allows access to anyone in that set.

Create a String matching condition with your protected strings. Create a rule that blocks anyone that references your URL string in the URI.

Make sure that the Whitelist rule comes before the Blacklist rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html), it can execute custom logic before response is returned to the client.

It requires CloudFront distribution.